# How to build a custom key for matching two queries, using Linq-To-Entities

Tags: linq, casting, linq-to-entities, key

I want to match in-memory entities to data from DB-tables and return a new in-memory DTO with a subset of that matched information. Now, matching involves two columns, thus I am **building a new key on the fly**. This works, as long as I execute the queries before building the keys, effectively using *Linq-To-Objects* for the matching.

When not executing the query right away, I receive a runtime exception as described by this [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738550%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

Here is my code and data model, simplified. I have

- Rooms (as `IEnumerable<Room>`, already in memory)
- Areas (as `IEnumerable<Room>`, already in memory)
- Alarms (from the DB, as IQueryable from the context)

Alarms are tied to Areas and LocationIds. Rooms can have multiple Areas, and have one LocationId.

I want to build a set of Alarms occurred in a set of Rooms. This involves matching the Alarm's Area and LocationsId to each Room's LocationId and the Areas.

```
from area in allAreas
let alarmKey = area.AreaName + area.Room.LocationId //AreaName is String, LocationId is integer
//....
```

However, this line involves a not supported cast form int to String. **How to create the key?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't mind a number of leading spaces in `LocationId` you can do

```
let alarmKey = area.AreaName + 
               SqlFunctions.StringConvert((double)area.Room.LocationId)
```

[`SqlFunctions`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.sqlclient.sqlfunctions.aspx) is in `System.Data.Objects.SqlClient`.